# Cypress - How to do negative lookaheads with RegEx?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, filter, cypress

I'm trying to test a filter in Cypress and once the filter is removed, the search result should contain values beyond the filtered value again.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
cy.get('.outputTableArea').within(() => {
    cy.get("td").then(($td) => {
        expect($td).to.contain(/^(?!regex)/);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, the negative lookahead does not seem to work with `(?!...)` here.

Comment: What did you plan to match with `^(?!regex)`?

Comment: That was just an example. It is a device list, I plan to match everything except the device that was filtered (in order to see if the filter is removed properly...)

Comment: Can you provide a link to `contain()` API? Does it support regex?

Comment: @OliverHowald Did you ever arrive at an answer for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a chai's [contains](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_include) matcher (alias of `include`) on a DOM element, but the API expects a string and doesn't take a `RegExp` needle, but another string (same as DOM's `String.prototype.includes`).

You can use [match](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_match):

```js
expect($td.text()).to.match(/^(?!regex)/);
```

or better yet, Cypress' [`.contains()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Syntax) or `.should('match')` (which uses chai underneath):

```js
describe('test', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    cy.document().then( doc => {
      doc.body.innerHTML = `
        <div class="test">Hello world!</div>
        <div class="test">Hello Steve!</div>
      `;
    });

    // using cy.contains
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cy.get('.test:first').contains(/hello(?! world)/i); // will fail
    cy.get('.test:last').contains(/hello(?! world)/i); // will succeed

    // using chai matcher on yielded text
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cy.get('.test:first').invoke('text').should('match', /hello(?! world)/i); // will fail
    cy.get('.test:last').invoke('text').should('match', /hello(?! world)/i); // will succeed

    // using cy.contains in a callback
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cy.get('.test:first').then($el => {
      cy.wrap($el).contains(/hello(?! world)/i); // will fail
    });
    cy.get('.test:last').then($el => {
      cy.wrap($el).contains(/hello(?! world)/i); // will suceed
    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What about testing your list's length to ensure that all of the results are being returned when the filter is removed? E.g. where '10' is the number of items in the full list:

```
cy.get('.outputTableArea td').should('have.length', 10);
```

If you need to check that a specific value is missing from the table contents, you could try:

```
cy.get('.outputTableArea').contains(/^regex/).should(not.exist);
```

Or maybe narrow it down to  tags with:

```
cy.get('.outputTableArea td').contains(/^regex/).should(not.exist);
```